# AlertDialog with DatePicker into Fragment with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement AlertDialog with DatePicker into with Fragment in Android Studio, when I implement it alone it runs fine but when I try to put it inside Fragment I have the following error, someone knows how I can solve this?

> Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager' in 'TerminalFragment'

```
public class TerminalFragment extends Fragment implements FechaNacimientoDialog.FechaNacimientoDialogListener, ServiceConnection, SerialListener {
.
.
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_terminal, container, false);

    myFechaNacimiento = view.findViewById(R.id.et_fechaNacimiento);

    myFechaNacimiento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialogFechaNacimiento();
        }

    });
.
.
public void openDialogFechaNacimiento() {
    FechaNacimientoDialog fechaNacimientoDialog = new FechaNacimientoDialog();
    fechaNacimientoDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "example dialog"); //<--ERROR!!!!!
}
```

Comment: why do you need an AlertDialog when DatePicker is already a dialog?

Comment: Because I'm using the old DataPicker presentation, Spinner type and this does not have the presentation of an AlertDialog

Comment: can u try `getChildFragmentManager()` ? I think this will works

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the following code

```java
public void openDialogFechaNacimiento() {
    FechaNacimientoDialog fechaNacimientoDialog = new FechaNacimientoDialog();
    fechaNacimientoDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "example dialog"); //<--ERROR!!!!!
}
```

This is because there is no `getSupportFragmentManager()` method inside a Fragment. To access this you need to use the following

```java
requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```